# How to use FFmpeg to get lyrics?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, media

FFmpeg version:3.3.2

I try to use stream to get lyrics,but that cannot.

Code:

```
AVFormatContext* fmt_ctx = NULL;
int ret;
av_register_all();

if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, "media path", NULL, NULL))){
    printf("Fail to open file");
    return;
}
if (fmt_ctx->iformat->read_header(fmt_ctx) < 0) {
    printf("No header format");
    return;
}
for (uint i = 0; i < fmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++){
    auto stream=fmt_ctx->streams[i];
    if(stream->disposition==AV_DISPOSITION_LYRICS){
        printf("lyrics!");//"will not print"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stream `disposition` is a bit-field so try without strict equality. The condition should be:

```
stream->disposition & AV_DISPOSITION_LYRICS
```